# Bind array to `datetime-local`?

Tags: angular, typescript, binding

I have a service which ingests a datetime represented as an array `(e.g. [2021, 09, 02, 08, 46] or [yyyy, mm, dd, hh, mm])`

In my component, the following property stores the ingested datetime above

```
public startTime : number[];
```

in my template I would like to bind this array to my input as follows:

```
<input type="datetime-local" [ngModel]="startTime" />
```

Is there a clean way to bind `startTime`, representing the year/month/day/hour/time as an array, to `datetime-local`?  I don't want to do a bunch of casts or conversions, if I don't need to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you will probably need some casting.

```
const startTime = new Date(...startTimeArray);
```

With a `Date` object you can play with it any way you like:

```
<input type="datetime-local" [ngModel]="startTime | date:'yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm'" (ngModelChange)="startTime = parseDateEvent($event)"/>
```

```
parseDateEvent(date: string) {
   return !!date ? new Date(date) : null;
}
```